GeoServer permissions unable to be adjusted
While interacting with a map in OpenLayers, I am trying to WFS-update a shapefile that I uploaded to GeoServer. After some struggles I am now facing this issue:

WFS-T Response: <ows:ExceptionReport
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0.0"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/ows/1.0.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd">
<ows:Exception exceptionCode="NoApplicableCode">
ows:ExceptionText{http://www.geoserver.org/workspace}layer is read-only</ows:ExceptionText>   </ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>

So in GeoServer, I am trying to enable write-permissions for all users (especially ROLE_ANONYMOUS) in the Security-tab for my workspace. Then I get the red error-message in the browser:

Failed to move
C:\ProgramData\GeoServer\security\layers.properties.6dd42759-9166-41b3-acb4-badf06da9d8b.tmp

unable to remove existing: C:\ProgramData\GeoServer\security\layers.properties It seems like
GeoServer does not have permission to delete files in the
ProgramData/Geoserver-folder. I can delete them manually, but the
write-permissions are still blank for all users in GeoServer, meaning
no-one has write-permission(?).


I have tried multiple ways to remove the read-only status of the folder, including running Command Prompt as Admin and running code like:
attrib -r "folder_path" /s /d

but it keeps reverting back.

The user (hint probably not you) that is running GeoServer needs to have write permission to the whole data directory.
The first step is probably to move the data directory away from the install of GeoServer (this will stop paranoid security rules from locking things down).
Second, never give anonymous write permissions, that is an easy way to lose everything. You need to use a user with write permission (admin will do if this is one off, otherwise create an update user).

C:\ProgramData is used by the Windows installer (or actually %PROGRAMDATA%\GeoServer)` https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/datadirectory/location.html. I think that the one who has last edited the installer code has considered that it is a good place for the data directory. Or did you mix up "ProgramData" with "Program Files"?

I'm not a windows user so I couldn't possibly comment.
